# Theoretically logarithmic complexity but practically its linear

Tags: performance, algorithm, theory, big-o, time-complexity

Have a look at the following code to find X^y.

```
/* Find exponent in logarithmic complexity */
int findPower(int base, exponent){
     if( 1 == exponent ) return base;
     return (findPower(base, exponent/2)*findPower(base, exponent-exponent/2));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage :: logpow baseNumber power\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("%s ^ %s  =  %d\n", argv[1], argv[2], findPow( atoi(argv[1]),
                                                          atoi(argv[2])) );
    return 0;
}
```

Analysis shows that this has a complexity of theta(log(n)). 
But I ran it to measure time, and here are the results

```
Run 1: (calculating 1^500_million)
user-lm Programming # time ./a.out 1 500000000
1 ^ 500000000  =  1

real    0m5.009s
user    0m5.000s
sys 0m0.000s


Run 2: (calculating 1^1_Billion)
user-lm Programming # time ./a.out 1 1000000000
1 ^ 1000000000  =  1

real    0m9.667s
user    0m9.640s
sys 0m0.000s


Run 3: (calculating 1^2_Billion)
user-lm Programming # time ./a.out 1 2000000000
1 ^ 2000000000  =  1

real    0m18.649s
user    0m18.630s
sys 0m0.000s
```

From above we can see that the actual time complexity has linear behaviour rather than logarithmic!

What could be the reason for such a huge difference in complexity?

Regards,

Microkernel

Comment: Yeah! wrong analysis from side, as pointed out below, 
T(n) =2T(n/2)+c  => theta(n)

@FlopCoder Thanks :), your code runs blazingly fast :)

Comment: How much time did it take for the last case?

Comment: 0.02 Secs!!!  Thats impressive :)

Comment: I've no idea, why those down votes!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are actually invoking 2 function calls from each call. The recursion tree would be a binary tree of height `log(exponent)`, so the number of nodes in it will be `2^log(exponent) == exponent`. So overall it becomes a linear algorithm. You can rewrite it like this for better performance:

```
int findPower(int base, int exponent){
    if( 0 == exponent ) return 1;
    int temp = findPower(base, exponent/2);
    if(exponent % 2 == 0) return temp * temp;
    return temp * temp * base;
}
```

The trick is, you have to store the value of `findPower(base, exponent/2)` to get the logarithmic complexity. The recursion tree still has height `log(exponent)` but each node has only one child now, so there would be `log(exponent)` nodes. If you *actually* call it twice it will *degrade* the performance even more than a linear one. There's no need to calculate the same value second time if you already have that!

As @David Schwartz pointed out, the number of calls made in your code would be doubled if `exponent` is doubled. But when you save the values, doubling the `exponent` make only *one* more call.

Answer (score 4):

Your analysis is incorrect, it is O(N).

When you raise N from 1 billion to 2 billion, you have to do two power operations on 1 billion. So doubling N doubles the work that needs to be done. That's O(N).

Answer (score 2):

There is a formal representation of your algorithm complexity :

`T(n) = 2T(n/2) + c`

Where `n` is the exponent. Which gives

`T(n) = Theta(n)`

The analysis is incorrect.